# php post delete button

Tags: php, mysql, button

Hi i have a while loop which prints out all the usernames,names,etc from the table users but the thing that i need is a button which could run a query which deletes the user id on that line so basically at the end of every user's line there should be a delete button that delets only that user but without refreshing the page. i have this so far

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($theuser)){
    $accid = $row["account_id"];
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["l_name"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
                        <td><form action="" method="post" >
                        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submitdelete" value="delete"></form></td></tr>';}
```

But the problem i have is that if i put this line of code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitdelete'])){
    mysql_query("Delete from users where account_id='$accid'");
}
```

inside the while loop it will delete all users. If i put it outside the while loop it wont get the id.

Is there a way to for example write the name of the input like :
name="submitdelete34" and by 34 i mean the id of the user so in the while loop it'd be coded like this:

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submitdelete'.$accid.'" value="delete"></form>'
```

and make it work .

Please help me

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use the `mysqli_` ones.

Comment: use a hidden input

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to make a button outside the loop, which will delete all users on a page? (ie. you want one button for a group)

Comment: nice sql injection btw

Comment: wogsland, thanks im still new and im still learning and didnt know about the mysqli thing and will sure use it from now on.

Comment: [*You're welcome*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905490/php-post-delete-button/41905518?noredirect=1#comment70993213_41905490)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make it easier. Let's add a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="account_id" value="<?php echo $accid;?>">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submitdelete" value="delete">
```

Now in your php you can get the id:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("my_host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

// simple error handler
if (!$connection){
    echo "SQL connection failed: ". mysqli_error($connection);
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['submitdelete'])){
    $acctid = (int) $_POST['account_id'];// <-- gotta protect from sql injection.
    mysqli_query($connection, "Delete from users where account_id='$accid'");
}
```

**BUT:**

The better solution would be to not delete the record. and a field on your table that can be called 'active' and you can set it to a `TINYINT`. this way to delete a record, you set `active=0`.

If you deleted by mistake, you can always set it back up to `active=1`

**Note** that I have used `mysqli_` rather than `mysql_`. You need to update it all over your code to `mysqli_` because [the other is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). It has been removed from newer versions of php

Comment: they're using mysql_ and you wrote `mysqli_query`.

Comment: *"Note that I have used mysqli_"* - well this `mysqli_query("Delete` will fail.

Comment: This would work, but there's really no need to cast it as an int, is there? ...and really that might be the wrong approach if the account_id is anything other than integer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right, it will fail, and hopefully it will be a journey in discovery.

Comment: so...um... edit the answer to put the connection example? ;-) after all, you were the one who suggested they mysqli but have posted an invalid example. You're sending the wrong message here @Ibu

Comment: Well, the laziness was strong, but now I vanquished it. So thank you for persisting.

Comment: I just did what you said the hidden input and it worked thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

use mysql_fetch_assoc

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($theuser)){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["l_name"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["email"].'</td>
          <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
          <td><form action="" method="post" >
          <input type="hidden" name="accid" value="'.$row["account_id"].'" />
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="submitdelete" value="delete"></td></tr>';
}
echo "</form>";
```

in action php script:

```
if($_POST['submitdelete']=='delete'){
    mysql_query("delete from users where account_id='{$_POST["accid"]}'");
}
```

Comment: What if a malicious user changes that hidden field and then delete all the accounts in your DB?